# Running an executable off of a usb drive

Tags: debian, filesystems, usb, usb-drive, executable

I have an executable on my usb drive. I `cd` to the directory,  `./app` yields `permission denied.` So I did `chmod u+x app`. Then, `./app`. But still, `permission denied.`!

Then I read something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied#18960752):

> That command [chmod] only changes the permissions associated with the file; it does not change the security controls associated with the entire volume. If it is security controls on the volume that are interfering with execution (for example, a noexec option may be specified for a volume in the Unix fstab file, which says not to allow execute permission for files on the volume), then you can remount the volume with options to allow execution. However, copying the file to a local volume may be a quicker and easier solution.

How would I make a program run off of a USB drive, with or without the above mentioned solution?

Comment: If the usb have a fat based file-system, then there is no executable bit to be set. You also have to look at the mount options. Before doing this look at the security risk of running of off a USB (not just this one, but any that could be plugged in).

Comment: mount options - perhaps the mount has noexec.

Comment: if the executable is a "shebang" script you can launch it via the interpreter.

Comment: And if it's a shared library executable (nowadays "binary" almost always means this), you can run it via the dynamic linker (`ld.so`, typically invoked as `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to remount the drive with execute allowed goes like

```
sudo mount $THING -o remount,exec
```

but with an apropriate value for `$THING`. You can use the device name, or the mount point.

Comment: Will that allow me to read and edit the files on it, too?

Comment: yes,  it may make everything appear to be executable (eg, if it's VFAT format), but fille will continue to be editable and directories writable etc.